# How can I get a matrix of strings after subsetting strings in a matrix?

Tags: r, string, subset

I have a "little" problem. I have a matrix with strings and I want to extract some parts of the strings in each cell and I want to obtain another matrix.

```
library (stringr)
ma <- matrix (c("ab", "wz", "k2", "jk"), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
colnames (ma) <- c("c1", "c2")
```

I've used:

```
str_sub (ma, 1, 1)
```

But it didn't give me what I wanted (a list of the values)

```
and I want to obtain another matrix like this:
  C1   C2
  "a"  "w"
  "k"  "j"
```

Thank you very much for any advice or solutions

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```r
sub_ma <- matrix(str_sub(ma,1,1), nrow=nrow(ma), ncol=ncol(ma), dimnames=dimnames(ma))
```

Comment: Or you could simply use `apply(ma, 2, str_sub, 1, 1)`

Comment: If you like this answer, you could Accept it as an answer. Thanks!